# Why isn't this code parsing properly for the answer?

Tags: php, html

The code will not produce a calculated result for me.. can anyone help me?

The HTML displays properly, I can input the constants, they are updated in the URL. The PHP GET function seems to be working but not producing any results on the page.

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Constant">
 <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Constant">
 <select name="Operator">
  <option>Select Option</option>
  <option>Add</option>
  <option>Subtract</option>
  <option>Multiply</option>
  <option>Divide</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>
 <button type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">Calculate</button>
</form>

<p>The answer is: </p>
```

```
if (isset($_GET['Submit'])) {
    $result1 = $_GET['num1'];
    $result2 = $_GET['num2'];
    $operator = $_GET['Operator'];
switch ($operator) {
    case 'Select Option':
        echo "Error";
        break;
    case 'Add':
        echo $result1 + $result2;
        break;
    case 'Subtract':
        echo $result1 - $result2;
        break;
    case 'Multiply':
        echo $result1 * $result2;
        break;
    case 'Divide':
        echo $result1 / $result2;
        break;
}}
```

Comment: put second part of your code into `<p>The answer is: <?php here ?></p>`

Comment: your code is correct and working on my localhost. So the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Seems to be working. Are you sure you don't see the result at the top of your page or somewhere else?

Comment: Hmm, I am running as a .html file on my xampp localhost? what could cause it?

Comment: You need to save it to file with `.php` extension, not `.html`, otherwise the PHP code would not be evaluated (and also would be visible when you view the source of the page).

Comment: Even though the head information says `<!DOCTYPE html>?`

Comment: Thank you!! Legend